# SQL query a percentage

Tags: sql

The table `MyTable` is defined like this:

```
Student_id(int), course_id(int), pass(bool)
```

How can I get the `student_ids` with `pass_rate > 95%`?
Also the `course_ids` with `pass_rate > 95%`?

Thanks

Comment: update your question add that the related  tables schema a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY and HAVING Class 101

```
SELECT student_id, SUM(CAST(pass AS INT)) * 100 / COUNT(course_id) as pass_rate
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING(sum(cast(pass as int)) * 100 / count(course_id)) > 95
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you need conditional `avg`:

```
select sudent_id, avg(case when pass = 1 then 1 else 0 end) average
from mytable
group by sudent_id
having avg(case when pass = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0.95;

select course_id, avg(case when pass = 1 then 1 else 0 end) average
from mytable
group by course_id
having avg(case when pass = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0.95;
```

You can change the condition `pass = 1` with `pass = true` if your dbms supports it.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, to do so, say you have a column showing the scores of students, you do this;

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE scores > 95
```